# ASP.NET Membership Show "This type of user does not have permission"

Tags: asp.net

I am learning the ASP.NET Membership and making an admin login page.
I have two types of users:
1. Normal user
2. Administrator

I want to show "This type of user does not have permission" when a normal user logins through the login page.

What should I do? I am using asp.net login control.
Add code in function Login1_LoggedIn? or Login1_Authenticate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I check roles in the Login1_Authenticate function and it works.

Answer (score 0):

You'll get this event sequence:

- Authenticate: that username/password matches anything in your database?
- LoggedIn: fires after a successful call to Authenticate; here you have access to user profile with `Roles.IsUserInRole()` method

This article series can be really useful to you: [Examining ASP.NET's Membership, Roles, and Profile](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020202857/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/120705-1.aspx)

Comment: That means I have to do it in LoggedIn method.
But how can I stop redirecting to destination URL?